# Reading reads strings from keyboard and writing them to a file

Tags: c, readfile

Here's my task and below you can find my specific question and the code I wrote:

Write a program that reads strings and writes them to a file. The string must be dynamically
allocated and the string can be of arbitrary length. When the string has been read it is written to the
file. The length of the string must be written first then a colon (‘:’) and then the string. The program
stops when user enters a single dot (‘.’) on the line.

**For example:**

User enters: `This is a test`
Program writes to file: `14:This is a test`

**Question:**

My code adds the number of characters and the colon, but not the string I typed, and when entered "." it wont exit

This is the code I have so far:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_SZ 256

int main() {

    char key[] = ".";

    char *text;
    int i;

    text = (char*)malloc(MAX_NAME_SZ);

    FILE* fp;

    do {
        printf("Enter text or '.' to exit: ", text);
        fgets(text, MAX_NAME_SZ, stdin);

        for (i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; ++i);

        printf("%d: %s", i);

        fp = fopen("EX13.txt", "w");

        while ((text = getchar()) != EOF) {
            putc(text, fp);
        }

        fclose(fp);
        printf("%s\n", text);


    } while (strncmp(key, text, 1) != 0);
    puts("Exit program");


    free(text);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read the compiler warnings and treat them as errors.

Comment: Consider reading [this C reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (maybe [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). See also [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) and [MILEPOST GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILEPOST_GCC). Notice that some computers (probably the servers running [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)....) don't have any keyboard. BTW, your code don't compile on Linux (with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) because missing stuff, e.g. `int main(int argc, char**argv) {`

Comment: Please provide some [mre]. If you use `ReadFile` please take some time to read [Windows documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/), since it is not mentioned in the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf). Read also [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

Comment: Your last edit modified the question so that th existing answers didn't make sense anymore. I rolled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for strings that are shorter than 255 chars.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_SZ 256


int main()
{
     
     char key[] = ".\n";
     char *text;

     text = (char*)malloc(MAX_NAME_SZ);
     if (text == NULL)
     {
             perror("problem with allocating memory with malloc for *text");
             return 1;
     }

     FILE *fp;
     fp = fopen("EX13.txt", "w");
     if (fp == NULL)
     {
             perror("EX13.txt not opened.\n");
             return 1;
     }

     printf("Enter text or '.' to exit: ");
     while (fgets(text, MAX_NAME_SZ, stdin) && strcmp(key, text))
     {
             fprintf(fp, "%ld: %s", strlen(text) - 1, text);
             printf("Enter text or '.' to exit: ");
     }

     free((void *) text);
     fclose(fp);

     puts("Exit program");

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Good people

Comment: This doesn't work if the last line of the file does not contain an end of line character `\n` (yes this is a common scenario). Example: if the last line of the file is `Hello` (without an end of line) then the program will display `4: Hello` instead of `5: Hello`.

Comment: @Filip Emanuel Drexler: Thanks! The only thing missing in the code is how to make the string dynamically allocated so that the string can be of arbitrary length?

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues in your code, almost everything is wrong.

Just a few problems:

- You use `printf("%d: %s", i);` to print on the screen what should go into the file.
- The loop `while ((text = getchar()) != EOF)` doesn't make any sense.
- You're closing the file after the first line entered
- You ignore all compiler warnings
- The end condition `while (strncmp(key, text, 1) != 0)` is wrong, you're only testing if the string *starts* with a `.`, and you're testing it too late.

This could be a start:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_SZ 256

int main() {
  char* text;
  int i;

  text = (char*)malloc(MAX_NAME_SZ);

  FILE* fp;
  fp = fopen("EX13.txt", "w");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("Can't open file\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  do {
    printf("Enter text or '.' to exit: ");
    fgets(text, MAX_NAME_SZ, stdin);

    if (strcmp(".\n", text) == 0)
      break;

    for (i = 0; text[i] != '\0' && text[i] != '\n'; ++i);

    fprintf(fp, "%d: %s", i, text);

  } while (1);

  fclose(fp);

  puts("Exit program");
  free(text);
  return 0;
}
```

There is a limitation though, in this program the maximum line length is 254 characters, not including the newline character. As far as I understood, the line length must be arbitrary.

I let you do this on your own as an exercise, but at your C knowledge level it will be hard.

Comment: @MarcusAbrate well just ask.

Comment: what does this line do?       for (i = 0; text[i] != '\0' && text[i] != '\n'; ++i);

Comment: @MarcusAbrate it counts the number of characters before the end of the string or before the end of line character (`\n`). So if your string is `"Hello"`, the length in `i` will be 5, if the stgring is `"Hello\n"` the length will also be 5. In other words: it counts the length of the string ignoring the end of line character. Read the documentation of `fgets`.